# Verify method calls another method from same class in Java

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android using Java and have a class which is subclass of base activity class. A method in my sub-class calls another method from the base class. In unit test, I want to verify that the method in the base class gets called with the subclass method is executed. How do I do that?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  public void myMethod() {
    moveTaskToBack(false);
  }
}
```

**Below is what I tried:**

```
MyActivity myActivity = new MyActivity();
final Activity mockActivity = Mockito.spy(Activity.class);
myActivity.myMethod();
Mockito.verify(mockActivity, Mockito.times(1)).moveTaskToBack(false);
```

**Error am seeing:**

```
Wanted but not invoked:
myActivity.moveTaskToBack(false);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Am I not testing it right?

Comment: Why you are creating non-spy object. Try to call myMethod on spy and see if moveTaskToBack is called. Spy should be of MyActivity type

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Mockito much, but have you tried changing

`Mockito.verify(mockActivity, Mockito.times(1)).moveTaskToBack(false);`

to

`Mockito.verify(myActivity, Mockito.times(1)).moveTaskToBack(false);`?

It seems like you're testing the wrong activity object

Comment: Yeah I tried that... I am getting this error with it:
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type MyActivity and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!

Also am not sure why it's showing different activity object in the initial error.

Comment: Hate to say it, but this is about where my Mockito knowledge/guessing runs short. I don't fully understand why Mockito would insist that spied objects are mocks, but it seems like it defeats the point of spying. The only thing I could suggest trying is `MyActivity myActivity = Mockito.spy(MyActivity.class)`

Comment: Oh, and combining that with using `Mockito.verify` on `myActivity`, since `mockActivity` is a wholly separate object, so there's no way to get the test to work by verifying it

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

```
MyActivity myActivity = Mockito.spy(MyActivity.class);
myActivity.myMethod();
Mockito.verify(myActivity, Mockito.times(1)).moveTaskToBack(false);
```

You don't need to care about parent class because subclass is a type of superclass. MyActivity is Activity. To put it in another way, you have the exactly same moveTaskToBack() method in MyActivity class and actually you are calling it.

Of course you can explicitly call the method with parent's reference super.moveTaskToBack(false), but this make no any sense for your use case. In this case the the test will fail, because moveTaskToBack will be called by super's reference